# Can't connect BLE via HC-06

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno

Here is the problem, I tried to connect BLE via HC-06(on Arduino Uno) on my phone, it showed that "Can't communicate with BT01".
[Can't communicate with BT01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86TIx.png)

But when using some apps like BLE Scanner, I can connect BLE on the phone and transfer data between phone and Arduino.[Connect successfully and transfer "successful" to Arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KJyh.png)

Here are some data about Arduino.

GND ---------------- G(GND)

VCC ---------------- 5V

TXD -----------------10

RXD -----------------11

[Arduino Uno and HC-06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR0r4.jpg)
[Arduino Serial Monitor and the picture of trying to connect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTsVM.png)

```
//When receiving data, print it.
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11);  // RX | TX on Arduino
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");
  BTSerial.begin(9600);  // HC-06 current bound rate (default 9600)
}

void loop() {
  // Keep reading from HC-06 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
  if (BTSerial.available())
    Serial.write(BTSerial.read());
  // Keep reading from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-06
  if (Serial.available())
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

I tried to change the password, check the wiring correctly and change the wiring position on Arduino, reboot the computer, and use other phone, but it didn't work.

Can anyone help?thx

Comment: HC-06 doesn't speak BLE. it knows only classic Bluetooth

Comment: The HC-06 is Bluetooth Classic not BLE. Try using an app on your phone for classic e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal

Comment: The screenshots you show of it not working looks to be in the Android Bluetooth settings. In the other screenshot it shows that it is a BLE device with a custom service and a custom characteristic. This means that your phone will not know how to communicate with it without an app to tell it specifically how to work with that custom UUID. Generic BLE scanning and exploration tools will allow you to interact with custom services.

Comment: I understand, so I can't connect them directly, I need to use other app to do it, thank you Juraj and ukBaz.